# How can I consider the noise from my neighbor in V2X?

Tags: wireless, throughput, v2v, vehicular

I'm working in v2x and I'm trying to calculate the date rate for specific vehicles in the road. How can I consider the other neighbor's vehicle's interference when calculating the date rate for my specific vehicles. I know the other vehicle's position and the distance between the choosing vehicles and the others but I don't know if they are sending or not.
Is there any specific way to calculate the correct data rate of choosing vehicles?

Comment: If you're asking about noise on the physical layer, you should consider the [Electronics SE site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, you need to make your question much clearer.

Comment: @Zac67 thanks, I will consider the Electronics SE site